# why the result not contain imaginary, I?

Tags: matrix, complex, coding-style, infinite-loop

Good day,

First of all, sorry if my coding in this forum has mistake. I already learned it and this is the best try from me.

May anyone help me troubleshoot my problem below.

```
β1 = 0; 
β3 = Pi; 
β2 = Pi/2;
For[t = 0, t < 10, t++,
    A={{E^(I β1 + I β3) Cos[t*β2],   E^(I β1 - I β3) Sin[t*β2]},
  {(-E^((-I) β1 + I β3)) Sin[t*β2], E^((-I) β1 - I β3) Cos[t*β2]}}; 
   Print[A];Print[t];t = t + TimeUsed[]]
```

I get the output as example as below,

```
{{1,0},{0,1}}

0

{{-0.740687,0.67185},{-0.67185,-0.740687}}

1.531

{{0.122216,-0.992504},{0.992504,0.122216}}

3.078

{{0.55557,0.83147},{-0.83147,0.55557}}

4.625

{{-0.963724,-0.266902},{0.266902,-0.963724}}

6.172

{{0.904157,-0.4272},{0.4272,0.904157}}

7.719

{{-0.40578,0.913971},{-0.913971,-0.40578}}

9.266
```

suppose the answer will include the symbol I. But what the mistake that I did.?

Thank you

---

Thank you for the @Edmund according to Euler Formula. I already read that and it correct output from the coding.

Since the Euler Formula is given by,

```
e^(ix)= Cosx+ iSinx.
```

where the x in angle rotating the plane.

Thank you

Comment: I don't get your results.  However, have a read of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) from complex analysis and you see that the $e^{i n x}$ are evaluating to either 1, 0, or -1 in your formulas.

Comment: @Edmund, I edit it for the output.when i calculate manually, the result suppose include I.why?.

Comment: what is the logic behind incrementing t by timeused??

Comment: @george2079, actually, I want to see the changes of the value when I increase the time by used time provided by computer system. From my reading, timeused is time given by computer. But why the I is not included in the output?

Comment: Change beta1 and/or beta2 to anything but 0 and Pi, and the answer will be imaginary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem seems to stem from a possible misunderstanding of the underlying math, and not from the code.

Comment: BUT `t` is your *loop iterator* and it appears in your calculation.  I see no sense to why your expression should depend on the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am putting it as an answer just to remove this question from the unanswered queue.

```
Table[{x, Exp[I x] // N}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/2}] // TableForm
```

$
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1. \\
 \frac{\pi }{2} & 0.\, +1. i \\
 \pi  & -1. \\
\end{array}
$